# Multiple Concurrent SQL Queries - Performance Inquiry

Tags: java, mysql

So I've been browsing questions that may already have my answer, but they do not directly answer my question, my situation is I'd like to write a plugin for a game that will collect statistics, one of them would be collecting a statistic that could potentially with enough players in the server be about easily 200 queries within 3 seconds, on the specifications shown below, querying a remote database I have two questions, the first being, is this going to cause noticeable network issues on a 100Mbit port, and my second question being, will all the queries show tremendous amounts of CPU usage on top of a highly intensive game engine that takes a lot of CPU usage?

**Server Specifications**

```
- i3 3420 4 Cores
- 16GB RAM
- 100Mbit Port
```

*On a Side Note,*

Would moving the database to the local server reduce potential usage to the point where it's highly recommended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, without knowing the amount of data being stored, it's hard to make any judgement calls on this one. However, a couple of things...

- I doubt any database could handle 200 queries in 3 seconds on that kind of machine, unless you have tables with only a few records.
- The 100mbit port won't be a problem; you're not actually transporting the whole database across the wire, just the query ("SELECT FROM ...") and the results (which should be a single row for statistics).

However, you *will* bog down the server with such queries, causing hickups and delays for your gamers. My recommendation for you would be to replicate the gamedatabase to a separate server (a simple Master/Slave setup) and perform your statistics queries on the slave database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer =) To add a bit more info, to make things a bit more easier to give a better answer, the game in question is Minecraft which you may or may not have heard of it, you literally place and break blocks, and that's the statistic I had in mind, not 100% needed, but I thought it'd be a cool thing, but if it has a very large impact it's obviously not worth it. the query would be rather simple. My website requires you to register an account ingame, so the query would be quite simple, update stats SET blocksplaced = blocksplaced + 1 WHERE username = playername. Very simple.

Comment: Ah, so you are talking about 200 **UPDATES** per 3 seconds, not 200 **QUERIES**. Ouch. That is most likely not going to work at all.